# Divider that is responsive to various text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design a reusable content separator that has text in the middle. The text will be passed in dynamically, so it will vary in length.

The idea is this:

```
-----------------------  MAIN SECTION  ----------------------- 

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed no etiam nonumes. 
  Eam ea prima mandamus senserit, etiam nonumes ad pro. 

-------------------  ANOTHER SECTION MORE  -------------------

  Aliquid platonem nam an, nihil volumus menandri sed ex. 
  Eum malis imperdiet no, paulo decore vituperata te vis, 
  sed cu nisl scripta. Meliore efficiantur te mei, 
  his ne vivendo accusata.

------------------------  CONTACT US  ------------------------

  Nostro salutatus quo ea, duo ex denique conceptam.
  Ad sea zril iuvaret, ex mei cetero facilisis voluptatum.
  Duo nonumy facilis ne, ius nisl aperiri inermis ea.
```

---

As you can see, these reusable components separate (and label) content on a web page.

Here is a **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/5b446ed20ad5e39e067aa60866f95615)** of the idea.

So far I have been dividing the separator horizontally into 3 columns. The dotted lines have a width of `5/12`, and the text has a width of `1/12`.

---

Problems:

- the text column width of `1/12` is too small for longer text, especially on smaller screen widths

  - the text shouldn't wrap, but rather it should be on the same line as the dotted
    lines
- a larger width on the text column makes the space between the dotted lines and the text too big when the screen size is increased and the text length is decreased

---

This leads me to believe that the column approach won't work.

I've tried applying `display: table` on the separator container and giving each column `display: table-cell`, but I haven't been successful with this either.

I need to support IE9+. Therefore, I can't use flexbox reliably. I need an approach that is IE safe.

I appreciate the help, and if I would be happy to clarify anything in case I wasn't entirely clear.

Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to provide your code in a [mcve] in the question itself. A CodePen Demo is of limited use to those users behind restrictive corporate firewalls, and if CodePen decides to delete it, this question will be pretty much useless.

Comment: Very true - I just didn't want to clog the question with all that code but I don't mind posting it here.

Comment: That's why the "Minimal" part of that phrase is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 very long pseudo elements with dash border that will be positioned absolutely before and after the text element. The container of the text element should have overflow hidden to cut the redundant parts of the pseudo elements.

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h2 span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

h2 span::before, h2 span::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 1000px;
  border-top: 1px dashed;
  content: '';
}

h2 span::before {
  right: 100%;
}

h2 span::after {
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h2><span>Short</span></h2>
<h2><span>A bit longer</span></h2>
<h2><span>This is even longer</span></h2>
<h2><span>Longer Text Even Longer Sometimes This Happens</span></h2>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for this help.

Answer (score 2):

What you have are not dividers, you have headings, so make sure your markup is semantic:

```
<h1>Main Section</h1>
```

From there you want your text to be centered at 1/6th the full width, which is easy enough to do with padding. 1/6 is `16.667%` of the width, which leaves `5/6` to be padded on either side, which leaves `5/12` per side, which is `41.667%` padding:

```
h1 {
  padding: 0 41.667%;
}
```

Of course you also want your text to actually be centered in that region, so use `text-align`:

```
h1 {
  padding: 0 41.667%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Now for the hard part, you want the dotted line to be in the background of the text, but also remain centered across lines. You can use `background-position` to center the image, and `repeat-x` to make sure that it doesn't repeat vertically:

```css
h1 {
  background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/355833/pattern-dots.svg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  padding: 0 41.667%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Main Section</h1>
```

So far so good, except now we need to exclude the dots from the center of the image. The trick is to add *another* `background-image` to the heading. We want to overlay a properly sized white background on top of the dotted background image, so we'll have to list the overlay background-image *first*.

For this example, I'll be using an image generated using `linear-gradient`, but for IE9 support you'll need to use an image of a white pixel or a `data:` URI of a white SVG.

```
h1 {
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(to right, white 0%, white 100%),
    url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/355833/pattern-dots.svg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  padding: 0 41.667%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

The problem now is that the white background image is still repeating over top the dotted background. You can add `no-repeat` to the `background-repeat` args:

```
h1 {
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(to right, white 0%, white 100%),
    url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/355833/pattern-dots.svg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat:
    no-repeat,
    repeat-x;
  padding: 0 41.667%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

The last problem to solve is that the white background is still too large, as the `linear-gradient` is filling up the entire background of the node. If you use a single pixel background image it'll be too small. We can fix the size of the white background by using `background-size`.

We want it to be as wide as the gap between the padding, which was `16.667%` from earlier, and we want it to be `100%` of the node's height:

```css
h1 {
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(to right, white 0%, white 100%),
    url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/355833/pattern-dots.svg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat:
    no-repeat,
    repeat-x;
  background-size:
    16.667% 100%,
    auto;
  padding: 0 41.667%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Main Section</h1>
```

If you'd like to add some gutters between your text and your dotted background, you can either make the width of the white background a bit wider either as a percentage or by using `calc(16.667% + 10px)` where `10px` is twice the space you want on either side of the text.

```css
h1 {
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(to right, white 0%, white 100%),
    url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/355833/pattern-dots.svg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat:
    no-repeat,
    repeat-x;
  background-size:
    calc(16.667% + 10px) 100%,
    auto;
  padding: 0 41.667%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Main Section</h1>
```

Comment: I learned a lot from reading this detailed and informative answer. Thank you. I don't want the text to wrap though. I should have made that more clear at the beginning of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4m3zaw4s/1/)

CSS:

```
h4 {
    text-transform: none !important;
   width: 100%; 
   text-align: center; 
   border-bottom: 2px dotted #4cadc9; 
   line-height: 0.1em;
   margin: 10px 0 20px; 
} 

h4 span { 
    background:#fff; //your bg color 
    padding:0 10px; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<h4><span>your text</span></h4>
```

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers, and are more likely to attract downvotes. Please *explain* what the solution you're showing does, and *why/how* that code answers the question.